# jquery-uiのdraggableでドラッグした要素を取得する方法

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

jquery-uiのdraggableでドラッグした要素を取得する方法を教えてください。

```
<div class="draggable">1</div>
<div class="draggable">2</div>
<div class="draggable">3</div>
<div class="draggable">4</div>
<div class="draggable">5</div>
```

これを

```
$('.draggable').draggable({

  stop: function () {
    var t = $(this).text(); // ここでテキストを取得したい
    console.lgo(t);
  }

});
```

こんな感じにしたいのですが。

Comment: `console.log`を直せばそのコードで動くと思いますけど…

Answer (score 1):

`console.lgo`とのスペルのミス以外、コードは正しいです。下記のコードスニペットを実行して、ブラウザのコンソールで結果を確認できます。

```js
$('.draggable').draggable({
  stop: function () {
    var t = $(this).text();
    console.log(t);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="draggable">1</div>
<div class="draggable">2</div>
<div class="draggable">3</div>
<div class="draggable">4</div>
<div class="draggable">5</div>
```